# How can a Java program running in a docker container obtain its own process ID?

Tags: java, docker, pid

How to get the ID of the Java process running in the docker container?

Just like using `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` in Windows or Linux.

Comment: Why do you think it would be different in Docker?

Comment: Depending on your setup, the process ID is probably 1.

Comment: The code `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` is work in docker container. Thanks for your attention.